# nginx location fix: Redirect to index.html

Tags: nginx

I'm runnning nginx v 1.0.4 and we're trying to do the following:

```
location ~ ^/$ {
  rewrite  ^.*$  /index.html  last;
}
```

Basically:  If the user gets to the the default domain http://www.foo.com or http://www.foo.com/   redirect them to http://www.foo.com/index.html

When I add this to my conf file, I get the following:
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive " " in /etc/nginx/myconf.conf

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use rewrite function without location

```
rewrite  ^/$  /index.html  last;
```

or for permanent redirect

```
rewrite  ^/$  /index.html  permanent;
```

to rewrite with parameters, e.g. http://www.foo.com/?param=value -> http://www.foo.com/index.html?param=value

```
rewrite  ^/(\?.*)?$  /index.html$1  permanent;
```