# Serve index.html at / aws ebs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, reverse-proxy

I am serving static files using the reverse proxy on nginx.

I am currently using a file`.ebextensions/static-files.config`.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /index: myapp/myapp/static
```

This works fine, but I must navigate to /index to have these files served. Is there an option to serve them at /? I tried using both "/" and a blank key instead of index and neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nginx redirection feature for this. You can redirect / to /index easily

NGINX documentation for this: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

or just use `rewrite  ^/$  /index.html  last;` ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8337492/970422